# Sharepoint 2013 Joins CSOM C# or OOTB

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, caml-query, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using Two list. Is this possible left join using caml query? or Two list available joins available in sharepoint 2013 with out programmatically?? Is this possible in sharepoint Rest api?

Lis1 and List2

```
List1 columns 
Coumn1             Column2
Developer            1
Tester               2
Senior               3
Lead                 4
```

```
List2 columns 
Coumn1             Column2 
CTS                  1
TCS                  2
HTC                  3
L&T                  4
```

```
Output
Coumn1             Column2          Column3
CTS                Developer          1
TCS                Tester             2
HTC                Senior             3
L&T                Lead               4
```

I need output like this query

```
SELECT List2.Column1, List1.Column1, List1.Column2
 FROM List2
 LEFT JOIN List1 ON List2.Column2 = List1.Column2
```

Answer (score 3):

A REST option is to `$expand` the query (see e.g.: [How to join two lists using REST API sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145925/how-to-join-two-lists-using-rest-api-sharepoint-2013)).

A CSOM way would be to use `<Join Type='LEFT' ListAlias='ListName'></Join>` in your CAML (see e.g.: [Sharepoint 2013 .NET CSOM CamlQuery Join](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77592/sharepoint-2013-net-csom-camlquery-join))

Comment: I am not using SharePoint lookup concept between two list so is this possible to join to list using rest or caml?

Comment: @Hasanshali `$expand` isn't restricted to lookup, neither is CAML's `Join`. Yet you need to have a common property (aka column) which is a key in joins.

Comment: if you dont mine pls can u write one rest api above list???

Comment: @Hasanshali you made me confirm my word, and in fact it actually is so that a lookup is a mandatory to have with REST API. Apologizes for stating that previously wrong. In your scenario, a lookup would obviously be a recommendation to have, so it's at minimum something to strongly consider implementing.

Comment: Is this possible in caml query?

Comment: @Hasanshali with CAML it should be. It's a more lengthy way of implementation again due to the lack of a Lookup column. There's an existing answer in [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/62859/21441). giving the details about how to.